# Mysql current id

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site, and when I login I want to see my user id, I don't know what code to use or what to do.

And I need it in a `sql` code to:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET ally='3' WHERE ID =THE CURRENT USER ID ");
```

Sorry for my bad English. Please help

Comment: When you login in, you should be reading the user record for the user that's logging in.... that record should have the id, so save it to session at that point

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql - The current user id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085848/mysql-the-current-user-id)

Answer (score 0):

the main concept of `login` is that the user logs in with his unique id.with the help of that `id` you have to `fetch the users` record.
the as per requirement write the sql as: `select or update`.